# featherlight.js: How to make nextIcon and previousIcon always visible

Tags: featherlight.js

I succesfully implemented featherlight.js plugin on my wordpress blog to display some photos as a lightbox.

By default featherlight.js shows up the nextIcon and previousIcon only when the mouse hovers a certain area of the image.

But I would like the nextIcon/previousIcon to be always visible outside of the image when the lightbox is invoked.

Made some tests with "span.featherlight-next" resp. "span.featherlight-previous" so that the left/right icons are outside of the image...but until now I didn't find out how to do it.

Does someone know how to modify the CSS file so that the nextIcon and previousIcon to be always visible ?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please read this -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It is not so clear what you are asking, and it is certainly impossible to answer anyway, since you are not providing the CSS or other details.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer. Well, I came up with a solution which satisfies my needs. In fact I just moved the previous/next navigation icons inside the border of .featherlight-image, and the icons just are just visible on a mouse hover (which is the default).

First I set a bigger white border to the image:

`.featherlight .featherlight-image {
        max-width: 100%;
        border: 32px solid #fff;
}`

then I fine tuned .featherlight-next & .featherlight-previous and it's span classes based from featherlight.gallery.css, like this:

```
.featherlight-next,
.featherlight-previous {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;     
    top: 25px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 80%;
    cursor: pointer;
    /* preventing text selection */
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;

    /* IE9 hack, otherwise navigation doesn't appear */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0);
}

.featherlight-previous {
    left:  0px;
    right: 80%;     
}

.featherlight-next:hover,
.featherlight-previous:hover {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
}

.featherlight-next span,
.featherlight-previous span {
display: none;
    position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        width: 80%; 
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 50px;
        /* center vertically */
        margin-top: -40px;
        color: #777;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #888;
}

.featherlight-next span {
    right: 7px;
    left: auto;
    text-align: right;
}

.featherlight-previous span {
    right: 0px;
    left: 7px;      
    text-align: left;
}


.featherlight-next:hover span,
.featherlight-previous:hover span {
    display: inline-block;
}

/* Hide navigation while loading */
.featherlight-loading .featherlight-previous, .featherlight-loading .featherlight-next {
        display:none;
}
```

Putting the background to white could also help hiding the white image border / frame so that the navigation icons are more distinctive when hovering:

```
.featherlight:last-of-type {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
}
```

Hope this helps someone ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Check the source. You'll find how the hide/show is achieved:

```
    .featherlight-next span,
    .featherlight-previous span {
        display: none;
        // ...
    }
    .featherlight-next:hover span,
    .featherlight-previous:hover span {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

So you simply need to override the `display: none` with your own custom rule.